# What is the limit of sum of split Wiener process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I wish to find the limit in $L^2$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$ of
$A_n = \sum_{i=1}^nW^a(it/n)-W^a((i-1)t/n))(W^b(it/n)-W^b((i-1)t/n))$

How can I go about that?

Comment: It would be a start to explain the notation which you are using (that is, $W^a$ and $W^b$).

Comment: I guess $W^a$ and $W^b$ are just two different Wiener processes.

Comment: So you want to know about Weiner chaos? Anyone with some knowledge on this matter can tell you about that limit object. (Or you can wait for me, I'll give an answer when I finish my other parallel projects) P/s: Of course under the condition that $( W^{a}_t, W^{b}_t)$ is a gaussian process.

Comment: One result I can tell you for now , so that you can solve this problem by yourself is that if your object $A_n$ converges in any usual convergence ( $L^{p} $ with $(0<p<\infty)$, probability, except convergence in law) to a limit object $A$. You also have :$$ A_n \longrightarrow A$$ in all mentioned above convergence.

Comment: well, I assume if the expected value of $A_n$ is zero so is the limit?

Comment: @user9102437 I would like clarification on what $W^a$ and $W^b$ are. Are they independent 1D Brownian motions? Or are they dependent in some way? It is not clear. If this is from a textbook kindly tell the name of that book along with the chapter/section from which you found the problem as well.

Comment: Also look up the notion of a *cross-variation* process. This limit object is related to the cross variation process, in the same way a (square-integrable) martingale is related to its quadratic variation.

Comment: $\lim A_n = \rho t$. This is quadratic covariation of two correlated brownian motions. See here https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/18/quadratic-variations-and-integration-by-parts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for not doing this in TeX-form but it is easier to understand in handwritten form. [image]

Fill free to ask if you don't understand smth in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $W^a,W^b$ are independent $1$ dimensional BMs.

Let $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(W^a(\frac{it}n) - W^a\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)\left(W^b(\frac{it}n) - W^b\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)$. Note that for different values of $i$, the random variables inside the bracket are *independent* by the independence of increments of a BM, along with the independent blocks theorem.

Therefore, $E[Y_n^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n E\left[\left(W^a(\frac{it}n) - W^a\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)^2\left(W^b(\frac{it}n) - W^b\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)^2\right]$

again by independence, the inner expectation breaks :
$$
E\left[\left(W^a\left(\frac{it}n\right) - W^a\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)^2\left(W^b\left(\frac{it}n\right) - W^b\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)^2\right]\\ = E\left[\left(W^a\left(\frac{it}n\right) - W^a\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)^2\right]E\left[\left(W^b\left(\frac{it}n\right) - W^b\left(\frac{(i-1)t}{n}\right)\right)^2\right]  \\ = \frac 1{n} \cdot \frac 1n = \frac 1{n^2}
$$

and when we take the sum, we just get $E[Y_n^2] = \frac 1n$. Hence it is clear that $Y_n \to 0$ in $L^2$.

---

Note that if $W^a$ and $W^b$ are correlated random variables and jointly Gaussian (note : if uncorrelated and jointly Gaussian, then they are independent by a well known property of Gaussian random variables), it is still possible to perform this kind of calculation, by creating BMs using appropriate functionals of $W^a$ and $W^b$.